# BindingFlags does not exist in .NET Core netstandard 1.2 class library

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

In a .NET Core class library project targeting both `net452` and `netstandard1.3` frameworks, I'm trying to move the latter backwards to `netstandard1.2` in order to extend back-compatibility.

Project uses `BindingFlags` enum and builds fine on net452, as well netstandard1.3, but it fails on netstandard1.2 with a number of errors, all looking either like:

> CS0103    The name 'BindingFlags' does not exist in the current context

or like:

> CS7069    Reference to type 'BindingFlags' claims it is defined in 'System.Reflection', but it could not be found

Currently, `frameworks` attribute in *project.json* is:

```json
"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.2": {
    "imports": [
      "dnxcore50",
    ],
    "dependencies": {
      "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
      "runtime.any.System.Collections": "4.0.11",
      "System.Collections": "4.0.11",
      "System.Collections.NonGeneric": "4.0.1",
      "System.Console": "4.0.0",
      "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1",
      "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0",
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "4.1.1",
      "System.Text.Encodings.Web": "4.0.0"
    }
  },
  "net452": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.IO": "",
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "",
      "System.Xml": "",
      "System.Web": ""
    }
  }
},
```

and it already lists dependency from `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions`.

*Show potential fixes* popup suggests to install `"System.Reflection": "4.3.0-preview1-24530-04"`, only to find that type still shows with the red squiggly line. Another *Show potential fixes* popup this second time suggests to install `"System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.3.0-preview1-24530-04"`. Of course without affecting the error, that's still there.

Building net452 side goes fine, errors are only on `netstandard1.2` build.

What's wrong with this `BindingFlags` type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [netstandard 1.5 diff](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/ee23a3d89e4fef48238e1fe5c768a58cc073ca6d/docs/versions/netstandard1.5_diff.md) the `BindingFlags` enum was added to the standard in the 1.5 version.

Before it was available through the [System.Reflection.TypeExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions) package which only supports 1.3 or later so targetting 1.2 doesn't work.